# How to deal with patents that others hold?

Tags: civil-law, patents

I am an aspiring inventor and in the best case scenario I will be developing smartphones but something that is a huge hurdle for me are the patents that other people hold. I mean one company patented a UI with rounded corner rectangles! Is there any way I can create mainstream devices that have patented parts without being sued?

This is the video that brought the problem to my attention -

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0uv5jFaJFk

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's very general and is better asked on https://patents.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The general answer is "pay the license fee, or don't get caught". Since that seems obvious, I don't understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: @user6726 is the license fee static or variable? and if so, what decides the price?

Comment: @user9391457 the owner - just like for anything that’s for sale or rent

Comment: It's negotiable. I take it you're trying to understand practices and strategies for negotiating a license: the folks at Patents have experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is no patent on a "UI with rounded corner rectangles". There are several design patents (design patents are not patents) owned by Apple, Samsung and others on phone designs that consists of a long list of design features, one of them a rectangular shape with rounded corners.

To infringe on such a design patent, you need to copy the whole list of elements of the design patent. You are free to copy any single element of a design patent, just not all of them.

You should be more worried about several thousand patents that Qualcomm holds that make it practically impossible to build a phone without infringing on their patents.

Comment: yeah in case you haven't noticed yet, I have no idea what I am talking about

Comment: @gnasher729 - In the U.S. design patents are patents. They are not utility patents or plant patents, the other two kinds of patents. It is true that in most of the rest of the world designs are protected by a mechanism very separate from their patent systems.

Comment: Qualcomm, Apple, and Microsoft has some serious patents. Microsoft makes serious bank off Android phones other companies manufacture, because they get about $7 per phone - $1 billion annually just from Samsung. They would get some from iPhones too, but Apple and Microsoft have deals sharing each others' patents.